# How do you make child div overlap on top of parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a html li to have a sliding animation to the left and slide back to the right but it will overlap on top of its parent div container.

right now I'm currently stuck on just making the sliding animation to the left.

https://jsfiddle.net/4ssxaqbp/

```css
#outer-container
{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue;  
}

#container
{
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
a{
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  background-color:red;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
  margin-left: -50px;
}

a:after, a:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    height:50%;
    left:100%;
}
a:after{
    bottom:0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
a:before{
      top:0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right top, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-container">
<div id="container">
   <ul>
   <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafas1111111111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafas11111111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>

   </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

pure html and css is preferred, but my gut feeling is that this is not possible and needs javascript. If it is using js, i'm guessing it needs to change the position of the a tag to absolute, but I'm unsure. Is there anyone here to help?

Comment: what do you want to overlap what exactly? The sliding animation seems to work. Which parent do you want it to overlap and when?

Comment: the one I'm looking for is that the red <a>, will be sliding to left and then slides to the right and will be on top of the green and blue background

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/4ssxaqbp/6/

Comment: not really, it needs to be initially hidden or looks as if its under the blue background and after on hover it will be on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

The text is sliding left using `margin-left`, so you need to adjust that

```
a:hover {
  margin-left: -35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this https://jsfiddle.net/4ssxaqbp/3/

```css
#outer-container
{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue; 
  position:relative;
  padding: 15px;
}

#container
{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
a{
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  background-color:red;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
  margin-left: -30px;
}

a:after, a:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    height:50%;
    left:100%;
}
a:after{
    bottom:0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
a:before{
      top:0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right top, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-container">
<div id="container">
   <ul>
   <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafas1111111111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafas11111111d</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
   <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>

   </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the one I'm looking for is that the red <a>, will be sliding to left and then slides to the right and will be on top of the green and blue background

Comment: @ThompsonSanjoto .. This is what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/4ssxaqbp/5/

Comment: not really, it needs to be initially hidden or looks as if its under the blue background and after on hover it will be on top of it.

Comment: when I change your green div to 100px instead of 100%, the red <a> appears on top of everything when on rest. it needs to be partially hidden on rest

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your needs are satisfied!

```
#outer-container
{
  min-width:400px;
  min-height:200px;
  background-color:blue;  
}

#container
{
  width:200px;
  min-height:200px;
  background-color:green;
  /* overflow-y:scroll; */
}
a{
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  background-color:red;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
  margin-left: -30px;
}

a:after, a:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    height:50%;
    left:100%;
}
a:after{
    bottom:0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
a:before{
      top:0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right top, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making one myself, it still have some weird

```js
function whichTransitionEvent() {
  var t,
    el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

  var transitions = {
    "transition": "transitionend",
    "OTransition": "oTransitionEnd",
    "MozTransition": "transitionend",
    "WebkitTransition": "webkitTransitionEnd"
  }

  for (t in transitions) {
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
      return transitions[t];
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  var conX = $("#container").position().left;
  var conWidth = $("#container").width() + parseInt($("#container").css('padding-left'), 10);
  var padleft = parseInt($("ul").css('padding-left'), 10);
  var arrowWidth = 10

  $("a").mouseenter(function() {
    if ($(this).css('position') == 'absolute') {
      //do nothing as its probably trying to revert back to relative
      return;
    }
    var myButton = $(this)
    var width = $(this).width();
    var x = $(this).position().left;

    var needToMove = ((conX + conWidth) - (x + width + arrowWidth))

    $(this).css("left", needToMove + "px")
    var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();

    $(this).one(transitionEvent,
      function(event) {
        if (event.originalEvent.elapsedTime == 0.3) {
          $(this).addClass('notransition');
          $(this).css({
            top: $(this).offset().top + 'px',
            left: $(this).offset().left + 'px',
            width: $(this).width() + 'px',
            height: $(this).height() + 'px',
            position: 'absolute'
          });

          var ablock = $(this);
          //can't find the right trigger on after $(this).css finished applying
          setTimeout(function() {
            ablock.removeClass('notransition');
            ablock.css("left", padleft + conX + "px")
          }, 10);
        }
      });
  })

  $("a").mouseleave(function() {
    if ($(this).css('position') == 'absolute') {

      //moving back the absolute <a> to relative
      //transitioning absolute to left
      var width = $(this).width();

      var needToMove = ((conX + conWidth) - width - arrowWidth)
      $(this).css("left", needToMove + "px")
      var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();
      $(this).one(transitionEvent,
        function(event) {
          $(this).addClass('notransition');
          var x = $(this).position().left;

          var needToMove = (conWidth - (padleft + width + arrowWidth))

          $(this).css({
            top: '0px',
            left: needToMove + 'px',
            width: $(this).width() + 'px',
            height: $(this).height() + 'px',
            position: 'relative'
          });
          //after 'finishing' converting back to relative move to right
          var ablock = $(this);
          setTimeout(function() {
            ablock.removeClass('notransition');
            ablock.css("left", "0px")
          }, 10);
        })


    } else {
      //if its still in relative state, just move it back
      $(this).css("left", 0)
    }

  })
});
```

```css
#outer-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

a {
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:after,
a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
}

a:after {
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}

a:before {
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.notransition {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer-container">
  <div id="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafas11111d</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafas1111111111d</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafas11111111d</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>
      <li><a>adfsafasd</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

buggy issues
https://jsfiddle.net/extempest/4ssxaqbp/17/